# Using data members to combine classes

Tags: java, member

I'm coding a card game in which I've created the Card, Card7, Card8, and Card9 classes. The Card7-9 classes all extend the `Card` class. However my teacher looked over the code and said something about how I could use data members to make it all into one class. I'm not quite sure what he means by that. Any suggestions?

Here's a sample Card number class(the other 2 are all similar):

```
public class Card9 extends Card{

    private String name;
    private char suit, color;
    private int life;

    public Card9(int x, int y, char suit, char color) {
        super(x,y, suit, color);
        name = new String("Nine");
        life = 9;
    }

    public Card9(int x, int y, int random, char suit, char color) {
        super(x, y, random, suit, color);
        name = new String("Nine");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you have 100 cards? Will you create 100 Card classes?

```
public class Card {
    private String name;
    .
    .
    .
    .

    public Card(String name, ........) {
        this.name = name; // set the name of the card to its global variable
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // create as many card objects you like
        // in the constructor, send appropriate card values for each card
        Card card8 = new Card("card8", ........);
        Card card9 = new Card("card9", ........);
    }
}
```